# How to store and get Data?

Tags: python, file, storage

I am new to python and I am wondering what would be the best solution to store and get data.

I need to store an Id and a score to it eg 89043298234, 6
then I need a routine that checks if the file already contains the id and if it does get the score and increases it.

Comment: Look at the `open` function, and (to get into good practice straight away) `with` statements. Then you will need to use `read` and `write`.

Comment: Google and [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) are your friends!

Comment: `numpy`s `savetxt` and `genfromtxt` could be of help

Comment: @embert Python != numpy!

Comment: I got your point, @sweeneyrod. But also consider he might not yet know about `numpy` (and therefore didn't take that tag). So this might be not totally off base..

Comment: @embert He might not know about numpy, but it doesn't really seem that relevant here. The question doesn't mention arrays or matrices or anything like that.

Comment: @sweeneyrod Well..yea. right.